# When should I use "opportunity of" and when "opportunity from"?

Tags: prepositions

Which is the proper preposition, *from* or *of*?:

> There are many opportunities **from/of** the energy turnaround.

Comment: I wouldn't use either - they both seem a bit "weird" to me. *"The energy turnaround **presents** many opportunities"*, perhaps. But "opportunities" aren't really a quality that can be said to reside *within* some process, so linking them with a preposition such as ***from/of*** seems a bit "flowery" to me.

Comment: Ok. So in the following sentence: "The analysis of the indirect risks and opportunities from/of the energy transition for non-energy- intensive industries is based on a broad survey.", should I rather say: "The analysis of the indirect risks and opportunities coming/arising from the energy transition for non-energy- intensive industries is based on a broad survey." ?

Comment: Prepositions describe a relationship between whatever the prepositional phrase modifies and the object of the preposition. In order to arrive a good answer to your question, you'll have to describe the relationship clearly.  What are some examples of these opportunities associated with the energy turnaround?

Comment: The new policies related to the the German energy turnaround create a demand for energy efficient products, and thus for innovations. The energy turnaround can, hence, also create new business opportunities.
Bottom line, the energy turnaround creates opportunities. This is the relationship I'm referring to. Thanks again!

Comment: @Juanita: If I were you I wouldn't try to cram so much into one sentence in the first place. For example, you seem to have committed yourself to only analysing the *indirect* risks and opportunities. Does that imply you think there aren't any advantages or disadvantages that *directly* arise from whatever "transition" you're analysing? Or are you just going to ignore those?

Comment: Thanks for the support, but I do not think that you are able to see the whole picture of the paper after having read just one sentence. Also, the paper was written by PhD of the research institution I'm working at and I'm just the one proofreading it. So no worries about content. I think I have my answer. I will simply rephrase it to "arising from". Thank you all again! Great help!

Answer (score 4):

Well I'd say "The are many opportunities *in* the energy turnaround." is better.

Some alternatives:

The are many opportunities *to be found in* the energy turnaround.

The are many opportunities *arising from* the energy turnaround.

The are many opportunities *created by* the energy turnaround.

Comment: due to, as a result of, stemming from

Answer (score 0):

Having now read OP's comment, I'd change "arising from/of" to "associated with."  It occurs to me that the verb/participle choice helps to determine which preposition works best.